# error : "Cannot convert Array to Object" Data Scraping script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm new to Javascript and even newer to google script, so please be comprehensive :)

I'm trying to build a little script to scrap some data from a bunch of URL. I' using `Parser library`. Here is what I've:

```
function getArray() {
        var newData = new Array();
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('my_id').getSheetByName('Sheet4');
        var urls = sheet.getRange(1,1,5,5).getValues();
        var fromText = '<span class="nb-shares">';
        var toText = '</span>';

          for(i in urls){
        var url = urls[i];
        var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
        var scraped = Parser
                        .data(content)
                        .from(fromText)
                        .to(toText)
                        .build();
        newData.push(scraped);}
        var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('my_id').getSheetByName('Sheet5'); 
        sheet2.getRange(5, 1, newData.length, newData[1].length).setValues(newData);
    }
```

It return me the following error : `Cannot convert Array to Object`

What I'm trying to do is looping on an URLs array so I can scrap some data from each one of these URL and return the results in my sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing  `newData.push(scraped)` to  `newData.push([scraped])`

Comment: my code it's not working. I guess I have another error somewhere however I think the answers is fine.

Comment: I don't use the Parse library, so I don't know about errors there, but I see that you are grabbing 5 rows and 5 columns with `var urls = sheet.getRange(1,1,5,5).getValues();` , but then settings `var url = urls[i];` which is asking for 1 row, 5 columns. This will not pass through the UrlFetch. You need to either change the last 5 to 1 on the `getRange`, or change `urls[i]` to `urls[i][0]`. Like I said this is all I can help with because I have never used the Parse Library.

Comment: hey Bryce. thanks a lot. I moved a bit and open a new thread here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793542/scrap-data-from-one-column-and-pass-result-to-the-column-next-to-it. However thanks a lot for this explanation, I'm totally lost with this (x,x,x,x) concept of row and column !