# Scrape data from one column and pass result to the column next to it

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've the following data scraping script (working with Parse library) :

```
function getData() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('my_id').getSheetByName('Sheet2');
var urls = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('my_id').getSheetByName("Sheet5"); // insert Spreadsheet Id and Sheet name
    var url = urls[i]
    var fromText = '<span class="nb-shares">';
    var toText = '</span>';
    var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    var scraped = Parser
                    .data(content)
                    .from(fromText)
                    .to(toText)
                    .build();
    sheet.appendRow([ url,scraped ]);
}
}
```

It's working perfectly however I've hard time dealing with the outpout. I'm taking my url from the first column of sheet2 so basically `A1:A` and I would like to pass the response of my script in the column `B1:B` in the same sheet.

`appendRow` just copy the value in the same column but in the rows under my url list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `sheet` twice, and I see that one is sheet2 and the other is sheet5. Is that correct or do you just want it on sheet2 like you said? If just sheet2, delete the `var sheet` in the for loop and then try `sheet.getRange(i+1,2).setValue(scraped)` This should work for what you are doing, but your script will run a lot faster if you put the response in an array and then set that array to the sheet after. Anytime a script communicates with the sheet it takes time, this is why we try to mitigate the times we call the sheet.

To do this:

```
function getData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('my_id').getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var urls = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var myNewArray = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {

     var url = urls[i]
     var fromText = '<span class="nb-shares">';
     var toText = '</span>';
     var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
     var scraped = Parser
                    .data(content)
                    .from(fromText)
                    .to(toText)
                    .build();
     myNewArray.push([scraped]);
}
 sheet.getRange(1,2,myNewArray.length,1).setValues(myNewArray);
}
```

This is a much faster approche and you will not run into the 6 minute limit google has on its scripts.

Two different approaches, but if all you are trying to do is put the response on the side of the URLs you can use the code I showed you in the first part.

Comment: Ok perfect thanks. two more question : how do you clear the column you passed the data in ( If I'm running the script multiple with different url). I tried this but doesn't work :  `sheet.getRange(1,2,myNewArray.length,1).clear();`. Also how do I select another column than the `A1:A` to build my url array ? Let say my url are in column c for example ?

Comment: I am assuming you want to clear the data before you put the new data in. If this the case I would do this. `sheet.getRange(1,2,sheet.getLastRow(),1).clear()` This will clear all of B1:B.

Comment: For the selection of the column, this is done in your  `var url = urls[i]` it should be for A `var url = urls[i][0]` so to change the column all you do is change the number.  `var url = urls[i][2]` because C is the 3rd column and arrays have a zero index. But getRange does not have a zero so always remember an array will be once less than the getRange number.

Comment: ok got it. everything is working fine. thanks so much. I guess I start understand the logic behind all this.